# Chrome Extension with Facebook: redirect_uri problem

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension using FB apis but this simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function login() 
    {
        FB.login(handleLogin);
    }

    function handleLogin(response) 
    {
        //if a user fails to log in...
        if (!response.session) 
        {
        document.write('Failed');
            return;
        }

        //searching users by the name of mike
        //FB.api("/search?q=mike&fields=name,picture&type=user", handleSearch);
    }

    //the API key of the application, change it to yours
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'c4a22dc0e8dc317cd80618bb9556e34d' });
</script>
```

won't be executed with the error

> API Error Code: 191 API Error
>   Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error
>   Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

I don't have a website nor I'm trying to link facebook to a website, I just want to create a chrome extension for my friends to use (like a little widget which would display contacts news)

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi Paul, Madhur, I'm having a similar issue. But the real problem is that there is no way to get the access token after requesting the facebook oauth url. The token is in the 302 redirect url which is transparently handled by the browser and there is no way to get it as what I have searched until now. I'm thinking of to use server-side flow or use a proxy server to handle the 302 redirect so that I have control to get the token. Did you have this kind of problem?

Comment: I just realized that url fragment is not passed to server. So the only solution will be using server-side flow authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and look for the section called Desktop Apps in the bottom.

You need to use this Url for dekstop apps:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Comment: Thank you, just a little info: this isn't the url I need to enter in the "Developers" page in my application's URL, right? This is the URL described in the section "Client-side flow" I suppose

Comment: How do you know if the user has logged out from Facebook? (not within your extension).

Answer (score 1):

You have have the success URL be one that is on your server, and have your extension run a content script on that URL. You can then use the chrome APIs in your content script to save the access token somewhere.